# CSS - Small amount of side scroll on mobile browsers

Tags: css

I have reduced the code for a site template down to this very basic page. Even in this basic state a small amount of side scroll is apparent when viewing on a mobile browser. This is tested on Samsung, default browser and Chrome.

It's not so much an issue on this demo but on the full template this side scroll adds a strip of blank page to the right hand side where the scroll bar is (underneath the scroll bar).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
*{ 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header{
width:992px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#000000;
height:90px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to eliminate the side scroll and have the page fit the screen exactly. As the site is fixed width and centred the width and margin CSS rules must stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `overflow:hidden` on the element that has the scroll if you want to hide that extra space that appears on mobile devices.